# Как понять модули в python

Tags: python, модули

Прочел я значит A bite of python и сижу где-то на 150-ых страницах Простого питона Любановича. Возможно я тупой, но объясните мне или подскажите, где узнать новые модули (или понять уже имеющиеся), методы и т.д. я пролистал страницы 2 в гугле, но на тех сайтах объяснения не лучше, чем в книгах. На англ. сайты и форумы я тоже полазил, но там информация, которую я осознать пока что не в силах. Буду признателен за рекомендации.

Comment: На ютьюбе посмотрите, там полно обучающих видео по питону прям с самых азов

Comment: Объясни для начала как понять твой вопрос.

Comment: Уточните, что конкретно вам не понятно.

Comment: Когда ты пишешь некоторый алгоритм практически всегда нужно остановиться и найти готовое решение. Сложность поиска готовых решений - одна из главных проблем в Python для меня. Знать всё невозможно и ты почти никогда не знаешь, что прямо сейчас пишешь велосипед =)

Answer (score 3):

**Для начала**, модулей в пайтон несколько десятков, если не сотен, тысяч, и изучить и понять их все человеку не под силу. Да и смысла в этом немного.
Модули изучаются по мере прохождения по этой сложной и извилистой тропинке изучения пайтона и становления девелопером. То есть, когда оно Вам понадобиться.

Допустим есть модуль `discord.py`. Он нужен в основном для создания discord-ботов. И пока вы не займетесь созданием discord-ботов он Вам не нужен, верно?
И все то же самое относится и к методам, типам и другому. Пока они Вам не понадобятся, изучать их не стоит, если только Вы не собираетесь в скором времени идти на junior developer'а.

Надеюсь ответил на вопрос исчерпывающе и понятно :)

Comment: `несколько десятков` — 235k тока на Pypi  не хочешь?

Comment: Благодарю, но есть ли хоть какой-нибудь список универсальных модулей, т.е. тех которые практически всегда пригодятся и нужны всем?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, `если не сотен. тысяч`. Не особо вдавался в количество, не интересно

Comment: @Daskis, нет. Всегда все зависит от задачи. Будет задача взять степень числа - тогда и ищите пакет с такой функцией (math). P.S. степень можно взять и с помощью `**`, это я к примеру просто.

Comment: @Daskis, нет таких, часто можно обойтись без модулей. Есть конкретные модули под конкретные задачи. Универсальных нет, и не понятно зачем такое вообще может понадобиться.

Comment: @Daskis Короче нужные часто: math, requests, datetime, time, threading, multiprocessing, re / regex, и тонна других это самые основные. Дальше смотря чего делаешь pyqt5, tkinter, kivy — GUI, flask, django, jinja2 — web etc.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, сейчас человек начнет это все изучать и смотреть. Зря путаете только:)

Comment: @entithat прав ;)

Comment: @Daskis Короче я сам имею и всем советую такой подход — учить, делать и т.д. только то, что нужно. Нужно гуи например — гуглишь питон гуи, смотришь чего выпало, пробуешь, что понравилось берешь ­— все ;)

Comment: Эх, писал, старался объяснить человеку, а никто даже стрелочку вверх не нажал

Comment: @piece0f нажал ;)